# Problema al ejecutar el comando de vercel dev en terminal cmd windows

Tags: javascript

hola a todos yo tengo un problema parecido espero puedan ayudarme :)... al intentar ejecutar el comando "vercel dev" me aparece esto:

C:\Users\TsUkAsASkArLeT\Music\JavaScrip\Proyecto\serveless>vercel dev

```
Creating initial build Running "npm run build"

@ build C:\Users\TsUkAsASkArLeT\Music\JavaScrip\Proyecto\serveless rm -rf public && mkdir public && echo 'Custom Build' > ./public/index.html
```

"rm" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! @ build: rm -rf public && mkdir public && echo 'Custom Build' > ./public/index.html npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\TsUkAsASkArLeT\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-01-11T20_35_00_063Z-debug.log Error! Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Comment: Pareciera que tu configuración es para un sistema operativo Unix

Answer (score 0):

yo tenia un error muy similar y lo que me sirvio fue instalar gitbash https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVh36sDppcs&t=307s
espero que te ayude bro[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: BIenvenido a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [answer]. Describe brevemente el contenido del enlace que proporcionas, ya que puede que no esté disponible más adelante.